# Os links externos deveriam abrir em novas abas?

Tags: debate, status-recusado

Durante a navegação, me deparo com links externos ao SO, e o clique (sem intervenção) abre na mesma aba em que estamos consultando e avaliando as respostas, tirando o usuário do SO. Creio que seria melhor que abrisse em outra aba.
Pensei também nas pessoas que utilizam algum tipo de leitor de tela, ou que não utilizam o mouse para dar os cliques. Pode ser irrelevante para muitos.

Comment: Infelizmente, é um erro de usabilidade comum, muitos devs acham que abrir link externos em outra janela/aba é uma melhoria na usabilidade. Geralmente não é. Veja [essa pergunta no ux.SE](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/19892/opening-website-external-links-in-new-window-published-usability-tests) e [esse artigo do Jakob Nielsen a respeito](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/the-top-ten-web-design-mistakes-of-1999/). É bem melhor não quebrar o botão voltar! =)

Comment: Interessante @elias vou ler o artigo.

Answer (score 13):

Eu prefiro como está, principalmente porque todos nós conhecemos (ou deveríamos conhecer) nossos browsers o suficiente para:

1. verificar no rodapé a URL do link antes de clicar;
2. forçar que abra em outra aba ou janela se acharmos necessário, via botão direito do mouse, botão do meio (rodinha) ou teclado.

Não acho que essa decisão deva ser tomada por mim pelos outros (pelo site). Se eu quiser abrir em outra aba, eu abro, seja o link externo ou não. Prefiro que o sistema interfira o mínimo possível na minha decisão, e isso significa deixar como está.

Não sei bem como funcionam os leitores de tela, será que têm algo parecido com abas? E será que abrir uma nova sem pedido explícito do usuário não seria um pouco desnorteante para quem não enxerga? Realmente não sei.

Comment: Ou então com o botão esquerdo do rato em conjugação com o CTRL que é o que eu costumo fazer.

Answer (score 3):

É bem simples, é só instalar o seguinte [*Userscript*](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/userscripts/info) e partir pro abraço:

```javascript
// ==UserScript==
// @name  (SE) External links
// @grant none
// @match *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match *://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match *://*.superuser.com/*
// @match *://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match *://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @match *://*.stackapps.com/*
// @match *://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// ==/UserScript==

var userscript = function($) {
    $('a[href^="http://"]')
        .not('a[href*=stackexchange]')
        .not('a[href*=stackoverflow]')
        .not('a[href*=superuser]')
        .not('a[href*=serverfault]')
        .not('a[href*=askubuntu]')
        .not('a[href*=stackapps]')
        .not('a[href*=mathoverflow]')
        .attr('target','_blank');
};

var el = document.createElement('script');
el.type = 'text/javascript';
el.text = '(' + userscript + ')(jQuery);';
document.head.appendChild(el);
```

Answer (score -5):

Eu me incomodo clicando em um link externo pelo fato desse link substituir a minha tela atual fazendo com que depois tenha que retornar ao site por outros meios fazendo-me perder um precioso tempo.

Quem está no SO só clica num link externo para compreender melhor a pergunta ou a resposta dada e não com intenção de sair do site e quem está buscando uma resposta relacionada a programação não estaria em lugar melhor para encontrá-la e nem sempre tem a destreza de pensar que poderia abrir o link em outra aba.

Comment: "nem sempre tem a destreza de pensar que poderia abrir o link em outra aba"? Mas este é um site para programadores!

Comment: Temos muitos iniciantes por aqui, bastante mesmo. Foi só o meu ponto de vista que não necessariamente seja o correto, simplesmente uma opinião diferente.

Comment: Claro, você tem todo o direito de dar a sua opinião. É que nunca me ocorreu que alguém que use este site (programadores profissionais e entusiastas) não conheçam um recurso tão básico do browser.

Comment: Acho que é mera questão de acostumar a usar control click, ou botão do meio do mouse ao clicar em link externo. De qualquer forma, se o problema é o iniciante não saber desse recurso, melhor ele aprender a usar, e não modificar uma coisa que já funciona.